# Synchronizing Google App Engine DataStore with local instance via Datanucleus REST API or some other Java API

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'd like to know if someone can guide me in this aspect, as everything I know is that Datanucleus REST API may help to make the contents of my local Google App Engine datastore and the online one the same. There might be also another way to do that which is easier, as I'm having great difficulties understanding how it could be done via that API. The application has been done in Java so there's no point in trying to develop it into Python now, it's way too late for that now.

Edit: Well I actually found some interesting tools here: http://www.appwrench.onpositive.com, but it would be better for my application if I could do it by code as it would need to be executed automatically once a day, so if you know of some not-too-hard way to achieve what I'm telling I'll be grateful if you tell me so, if not I'll just stick with the tools.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know DataNucleus, but you can connect GAE Datastore from local machines using [Remote API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi?hl=it)

> you can use Remote API to **access a production datastore from an app
>   running on your local machine**. You can also use Remote API to access
>   the datastore of one App Engine app from a different App Engine app.

With this, you can code an app to synchronize the data